# Replace null values using groupby.first() in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have a requirement where I have to replace null(NaN) values using the groupby.first element.

Test Data:

```
ID,Name,Cost
1,A,12
2,B,16
3,C,28
4,A,12
5,D,33
6,B,16
7,A,
8,C,28
9,C,
10,D,33
11,D,33
12,B,16
13,B,16
```

Cost of a Name(item) remains same throughout. Few of the Cost fields are not populated. I need to fill those missing Cost values as per corresponding Name object cost.

I tried the following, but it did not work. Can someone please help?

```
dataset['Cost'] = (dataset.groupby('Name')).apply(lambda x: dataset.groupby('Name')['Cost'].first())
```

I am using pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fillna` with `map`

```
s = df.groupby('Name')['Cost'].first().to_dict()

df['Cost'] = df['Cost'].fillna(df['Name'].map(s))
```

---

```
print(df)

   ID Name  Cost
0    1    A  12.0
1    2    B  16.0
2    3    C  28.0
3    4    A  12.0
4    5    D  33.0
5    6    B  16.0
6    7    A  12.0
7    8    C  28.0
8    9    C  28.0
9   10    D  33.0
10  11    D  33.0
11  12    B  16.0
12  13    B  16.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Datanovice